# Simple HTML DOM Can't get first TD in TR

Tags: parsing, html-parsing

I am having trouble parsing a table with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser 1.81 from SourceForge. I have PHP 7.1. I made this test to explain my problem.

I have this html file test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="workers">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bob</td>
                    <td>Plumber</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jane</td>
                    <td>Lawyer</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('test.html');

// creating an array of elements
    $table = $html->find('table',0);

    foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {

        $rowKey = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;

        var_dump($row_key);

        $value = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;

        var_dump($value);

        echo "rowkey=".$rowkey;
        echo "value=".$value;
        echo "<br>";
    } 
?>
```

I am having trouble getting the value of the first td for a row called $rowkey in my example. It is returning null.

I would appreciate any help or advice. Thank you.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using `rowKey`, `row_key` *and* `rowkey`. My advice would be to pick *one* variable name and stick to it :-)

More seriously, neither the `var_dump` nor the `echo` will use the variable you set to hold the DOM reference. Instead, they'll use some *other* value which appears to be, in this case, an uninitialised one.

If you change them all to be `rowKey` (or another if you prefer), it should work fine.

Comment: The row_key error is just in the test. It does not explain why the rowkey at the end does not have a value. I changed row_key to rowkey and it is still not working.

Comment: @user1964612, even if you changed it to rowkey, that is NOT the same as rowKey (with a capital K). As suggested, use ONE variable name.